# Where Can I Find the Source Code of Spatial Relationships Functions?

Tags: postgresql, geospatial, postgis, spatial, spatial-query

Where can I find the source codes of spatial relationships functions such as ST_Overlaps?

Comment: http://postgis.net/source ?

Comment: Did you make any effort to find the sources first? (-1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostGIS's git mirror is https://github.com/postgis/postgis . The master source is in svn. You would've learned this if you had done a Google search for "postgis source" and found [the relevant page on the postgis site](http://postgis.net/source).

`ST_Overlaps` is [declared in SQL as](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/4572ef795757df802519971a57ad75e09644bcb3/postgis/postgis.sql.in):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_Overlaps(geom1 geometry, geom2 geometry)
    RETURNS boolean
    AS 'SELECT $1 && $2 AND _ST_Overlaps($1,$2)'
```

which in turn refers to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _ST_Overlaps(geom1 geometry, geom2 geometry)
        RETURNS boolean
        AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME','overlaps'
        LANGUAGE 'c' IMMUTABLE STRICT
        COST 100;
```

so the C implementation is a function named `overlaps`, which is [defined in `postgis/lwgeom_geos.c`](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/bf2901b4736e283292c13f8213de0bb75af40828/postgis/lwgeom_geos.c#L1914) (found with `ctags -R` to build a source index, then `vim -t overlaps`, but you can use whatever C search tools you like, or just grep).